# How to change language in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

How to change jquery datepicker language, Here i attached view screenshot

I change month spellings inside datepicker.src.js, but i cant find week days coming from where

Please help me to show that in english

[Click here for calendar screen image](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qeWfhjVU_eD4FQG4IPg4bkEzXFG50iXX?usp=sharing)

Here i attached the link of whole file

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qeWfhjVU_eD4FQG4IPg4bkEzXFG50iXX?usp=sharing

Thank You.

Comment: Which Datepicker You Are using ?

Comment: Do not share the link for the code, instead share the sample code to for the date picker creation.

Comment: The links require additional access.

Comment: Sorry!!! Please try now, thank you

Comment: Hi TarangP
Here the link for that js, i download from one website

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vvFJDueRmfjf2QpDqC58Sx2PRm2U2fZl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change here

```
days: ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"],
        daysShort: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"],
        daysMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"],
```

**TO**

```
days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sonntag"],

        daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat"],

        daysMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat"],
```

Answer (score 3):

### Edit file "bootstrap-datepicker.js" to add your languages:

```
var dates = $.fn.datepicker.dates = {
            de: {
        days: ["Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag"],
        daysShort: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"],
        daysMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"],
        months: ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan","Feb","Mär","Apr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dez"],
        today: "Heute",
        clear: "Schließen"
    },

    en: {
        days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
        daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
        daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
        months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        today: "Today",
        clear: "Clear"
    }

};
```

---

you can use any language like:

```
$('.date').datepicker({ language: "en"});
```

or

```
$('.date').datepicker({ language: "de"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Download Language wise all datepicker files from here: [https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n][1]    I hope it will work.

```
 <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
         <!-- Script -->
         <script src='jquery-3.2.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

         <!-- jQuery UI -->
         <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
         <script src='jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

         <!-- Language script -->
            <script src="datepicker-fr.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
             <script src="datepicker-he.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
              <script src="datepicker-zh-TW.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
              <script src='datepicker-hi.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        </head>
        <body>

         Select Date : <input type='text' id='datepicker' ><br/>

         <!-- Script -->
         <script type='text/javascript' >
         $( function() {

          // Initialize and change language to hindi
          $('#datepicker').datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "hi" ] );

         });
         </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### in bootstrap-vue:

set `locale="de"` has done the job for me.

reference: [bootstrap vue datepicker - i18n](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#internationalization)